# let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and $A \subset \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, metric-spaces

let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $A=\{y \in \mathbb{R} : y = \lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)$, for some sequence $x_n \to +\infty$}$.$
Then the set $A$ is necessarily
(a) A connected set
(b) A compact set
(c) A singleton set

My Work:
I am able to show that the set $A$ is not bounded..So $A$ is not compact.I am trying to show that (c) can't be true by using some examples. Also I am unable to prove (a)..Need some help.

Comment: For some continuous $f$ the set $A$ might be bounded, e.g. $f=\sin$.

Comment: If I take the identity function then $A$ is unbounded..so $A$ can't be compact

Comment: @Saikat For the identity function, $A=\emptyset$

Comment: ohh yes yes...so identity function contradicts (c)

Comment: The identity function doesn't prove anything, since in that case $A=\varnothing$. Instead, try $x\sin x$ to disprove compactness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) is true by the IVT. Assume $y_1<y_2<y_3$ with $y_1,y_3\in A$. We will show that $y_2\in A$. Indeed, if $x_n\to \infty$ with $f(x_n)\to y_1$ and $z_n\to \infty$ with $f(z_n)\to y_3$, we may assume wlog. (say, after removing a few initial terms) that $f(x_n)<y_2<f(z_n)$ for all $n$. Then by the IVT, there exists $w_n$ bezween $x_m$ and $z_n$ with $f(w_n)=y_2$. As $w_n\to\infty$, this shows $y_2\in A$.

(b) and (c) need not be true, they are false for example if $f(x)=x\sin x$.